# Android studio 100% cpu , amd a10 not good?

Tags: windows, android-studio, cpu

Currently I have a laptop with forming a studio android programming, they are at first but I have some problems.
The configuration is: CPU AMD A10 4650m 4x2ghz, + 8 giga RAM, HDD 500.
Il simnt at certain times as remains blocked.

There is strong enough for studio android?
You would feel the difference when they replace HDD with SSD? or not?
I use Ubuntu instead of Windows?
Or is it necessary to use an Intel?

Comment: 2 types of desktop software can cause 100% CPU usage: benchmarking ones and crappy ones.

Comment: @Shomz You just called the VS C++ Compiler crappy.

Comment: @JameyD I was actually targetting Android Studio... the last version I tried was absolutely terrible.

Comment: but in the end, my computer has the power necessary to go right android studio? or?

Comment: It's not clear what your problem is. Having 100% CPU usage at certain times, like when compiling, is normal and even ideal.

Comment: then I can use it quiet. already scared me, I must have a minimum of intel i7. If instead of HDD, add an SSD will feel the difference?